# Is there a way to detect a construct?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, constructs

Assume that some plausible construct is pretending to be a regular stone statue.
**Is there a way for a group of PCs to detect that such a statue is in fact a construct?**
Without attacking or otherwise provoking it.
Bonus points if it works against any construct, from a distance, is usable from stealth and/or if it is not stopped by a golem's magic immunity.

I have not found any good way to do it.
As a mindless creature with a construct's immunities, it does not flinch no matter what the PCs do to- or near it, and it is immune to most things that affect creatures but not objects.
As a creature, it does not register under Detect Magic. Even if you were to make the case that a craftable constructs is also magic item, assume that the GM has already ruled against Detect Magic working.
Destroying the statue does not count as detecting the construct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

but it requires creativity and depends on how your GM/group handles how spells/abilities work.

For example, any spell or ability that works on creatures but not on objects [or vice versa] can be used to identify a construct creature. If you try to cast [Light](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Light) cantrips on every statue in the room, then the spells make each statue glow, but a construct wouldn't glow because the spell doesn't work: "**Target** object touched".

Since this method requires lots of spells, it's best used with cantrips/orisons/knacks or other unlimited use abilities. Non-offensive cantrip options are [Guidance](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Guidance), [Resistance](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Resistance), [Root](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Root), [Vigor](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Vigor), and [Virtue](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Virtue), though these are touch spells as well.

Useful non-spell abilities can also be found among a Witch's hexes or a Kineticist's wild talents, for example, since those usually have unlimited uses per day, e.g. [Scar](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/hexes/common-hexes/hex-scar-su/#) or [Foxfire](https://www.aonprd.com/KineticistTalentsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Foxfire). Hexes and wild talents are usually ranged and supernatural abilities, allowing them to ignore a golem's magic immunity.

Whether using any such spell or ability provokes the construct depends on your GM.

Comment: I wouldn't call abusing spell rules for the tabletop to be creative, but I suppose it could be. I agree that this is highly table-dependent (the tables I've played at have almost unanimously ruled against this because it breaks the narrative and highly meta-reliant. It's worth noting but I'm not confident it's the best answer.

Comment: A bit game:y, but technically correct. The best kind...

Comment: This is an *extreme* RAW reading of the rules to claim that a light spell only works on objects thus not on creatures. However, we can are this precise, then why not out another one: ["A construct is an animated object"](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterTypes.aspx?ItemName=Construct) therefore, does that not mean that RAW constructs would light up as well?

Answer (score 4):

### Perception check(s) vs Stealth

If a construct is attempting to hide in plain sight or imitate a statue, the GM should have it roll [Stealth](https://www.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ItemName=Stealth) (how [gargoyles](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Gargoyle)' and other creatures' [Freeze](https://www.aonprd.com/UMR.aspx?ItemName=Freeze) ability to remain undetected functions) or possibly something like Disguise; if they have a construct that typically does this, they may need to adjust the modifier on those skills or add the Freeze UMA to accommodate.

The party, assuming they are not too distracted, should then get *one free automatic* [Perception](https://www.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ItemName=Perception) check (and possibly additional ones if the players are requesting it, spending Move actions). This is how Paizo writers have handled it in AP's*.

> Action: Most Perception checks are reactive, made in response to observable stimulus. Intentionally searching for stimulus is a move action.

---

*I don't recall a specific example but will edit one in if I can find it.

Comment: This sounds like my preferred solution among the ones presented.

Comment: @Synapse If you wish, you are able to change your "correct" answer designation. It just brings this one to the top. You can also leave Teaitetos' answer checked, and mine will be around for people to see/compare.

Comment: Picking the Accepted answer was hard. Your answer is the better *solution to the problem* in my opinion, but I think Theaitetos has the better *answer to the question*, so that won out. Hope it makes sense. I'd love for all three current answers to stay around as they are all useful.

Answer (score 2):

[Knowledge(Arcana)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/knowledge) should do the trick. One of the uses is **Monster Lore**:

> You can use this skill to identify monsters and their special powers or vulnerabilities.
>
> **Check**: In general, the DC of such a check equals 10 + the monster’s CR. For common monsters, such as goblins, the DC of this check equals 5 + the monster’s CR. For particularly rare monsters, such as the tarrasque, the DC of this check equals 15 + the monster’s CR or more. A successful check allows you to remember a bit of useful information about that monster. For every 5 points by which your check result exceeds the DC, you recall another piece of useful information.

Along with the following table:

| **Creature Type** | **Field of Study** |
| --- | --- |
| *Constructs*, dragons, magical beasts | Arcana |
| Aberrations, oozes | Dungeoneering |
| Humanoids | Local |
| Animals, fey, monstrous humanoids, plants, vermin | Nature |
| Outsiders | Planes |
| Undead | Religion |

Comment: I did consider this, but it then begs the question, can you use knowledge(Arcana) to do Monster Lore on something that you do not (yet) know is a creature?
And speaking in-universe. If you take a Caryatid Column for example, it could look like just about any creature, it does not make sense to me that you could identify it before it starts moving around, unless you already have some extra information about the statue.

Comment: I feel like recalling information about something is different from recognizing if an object is actually that thing. It might be a valid response roll the GM gives you, but I don't think it's a reliable true-to-rules nor true-to-narrative solution. Especially because frequently, especially with constructs, two of the same creature may not even look alike.

Comment: If you know the thing and some weaknesses and strengths about it, that would also help a lot with figuring out if it's the real thing or just a statue. RAW, it automatically bypasses it, since it says "Identify Monsters". But if the GM wants the monster to *disguise* as a statue, they could have the construct roll a **Disguise** check, which as a rule would be opposed by perception.

Comment: I think having them roll stealth (like gargoyles do) or disguise against the party's efforts to search the room is a better answer than having your players running around trying to roll Arcana every time you say there is a statue anywhere ever. But a lot of constructs won't have those, so  I'm not sure that's the best solution either

Comment: That's probably what I'd do as DM, but I'm not sure that's actually in the rules. So I kept with what I know is in there.